# Populating a dropdown with recent years

Tags: php, date

I have a `<select>` dropdown with which I want to populate the previous 20 years as well as the current year. How would I go about this?

Comment: What effort have _you_ put in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to use [strtotime()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo strtotime("+1 year");
```

You can also use this inside a loop

```
echo strtotime("+".$i." year");
```

Where `$i` is the index in the loop.

Comment: This isn't what he's asking. I clarified the question a bit, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @obiask: $d = strtotime("now");
$a = strtotime($d-20);

Comment: @answer:for ($i=date("Y"); $i>1989; $i--) 
{ 
echo "<option>$i</option>\n"; 
}

Answer (score 2):

This should be all you need:

```
echo "<select>";
for ($i = date("Y") - 20; $i <= date("Y"); $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='{$i}'>{$i}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: this one looks like the most optimal +1. However would change the option echo to `echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";` Takes even less characters ;)

Comment: Do single quotes pass HTML validation? Not that it really matters here, but as I understood it, valid HTML only likes double quotes as attribute values.

Comment: @Jimmy: I believe it does. Never heard that it didn't before.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk::I want years starting from 1990 to current say.Say if next year comes then it should have 1990 to 2012.

Comment: Okay...replace the initializer in the `for` loop with: `$i = 1990;`. So you'll have: `for ($i = 1990; $i <= date("Y"); $i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
    echo mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+i);
}
```

Comment: I want years starting from 1990 to current say.Say if next year comes then it should have 1990 to 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a snippet like this:

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$min_year = 1990;

echo '<select name="year">';
echo '<option value="">Select Year..</option>";

for($i=$min_year; $i<=$current_year; $i++) {
echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: if 2012 comes then i get 1992.that twenty years should not change

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your needs then.  My solution above will always start at 20 years ago from the current date and count up until the current year.  Is this not what you asked for?

Comment: I want years starting from 1990 to current say.Say if next year comes then it should have 1990 to 2012.

Comment: I just changed the code above to reflect what you're looking to do